# Prevent jQuery from resetting after page refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The code below works great UNTIL page reloads. After page reload, my `.active` class just disappears.
How can I make this portion of jQuery immune, so `.active` class is still there after I hop between pages or just manually refresh the page?

```js
$('.myclass').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.myclass').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
```

```css
.myclass.active {

color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="myclass" onclick="location.href='http://example.com';"> </div>
<div class="myclass" onclick="location.href='http://example.com/page1/';"> </div>
```

Comment: you can't just `make it immune`. You can store data, either in localStorage or server-side somehow, and do stuff with that data to reactivate relevant classes if you want, but there's no automatic way of keeping bits of state after a refresh

Comment: What is the simplest way to achieve this with localStorage?

Comment: have a unique localStorage key that you use to keep track of each of these kinds of information, OR a localStorage key that has a json-encoded object with a variety of information, if you want to store a number of things

Comment: So if you only ever just want to store the `active-nav-class`, and it's simple and you just want to store one, then call it that -- `localStorage.activeNavClass = 'my clicked class'`, and then when a page loads check for that localStorage value and set it as appropriate

Comment: But it looks to me like it's not something you need to store in local storage -- you're really just trying to check if the current page matches the url in the `div`, right? So you can do that directly, rather than doing fancy things with local storage, by comparing the current page to the info in the div, using `window.location.pathname`

Comment: Answer: https://codepen.io/pen/QWKqaRG

Comment: javascript and html are pretty flexible, so you can tackle it any number of ways really. First, decide if you want to use sessionStorage or localStorage -- their apis are the same, but the length that the data stays available is different (sessionStorage only stores the data for that session)

Comment: then, since you're using jquery, I would add a `data-` attribute to each html element that you want to potentially save the active state for, something like `data-myclass-active="1"` for the first one and `="2"` for the second one, or alternatively `="myurl"` for each one

Comment: Then, in your onClick callback, `$('.myclass').click`, you can store the value of that attribute, `const ma = $(this).data('myclass-active'); localStorage.myclassActive = ma;`

Comment: then, when your page loads for the first time, you can set it up to check if `localStorage.myclassActive` is set, and if it is, find the element with the matching `data-myclass-active` property and give it the class `active`

Comment: I just can't make this to work.

Comment: well just do one thing at a time -- so first, figure out the part about setting the localStorage value, and seeing if the localStorage value is still there when you reset the page. Then, worry about activating the right element -- ask a new question if you have to